# How to install Media Explorer?

Tags: 11.10, compiling

[Media Explorer](http://media-explorer.org/) is a Media Center much like XBMC, it is part of Meego. The latest version, 0.3, is only available as source, which one has to build. A PPA exists, providing version 0.2, yet I don't want it--I want the latest one. The documentation lists the steps to build it in 11.04, but some packages just aren't found.

How can I install the latest version of Media Explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Installing Media Explorer 0.3.6.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

1. Install the prerequisites (I started from the list in [*itnet7's answer*](https://askubuntu.com/a/92385/58612)):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install intltool libclutter-1.0-dev libsoupcutter-dev libmx-dev libgrilo-0.1-dev libgstreamermm-0.10-dev libclutter-gst-dev liblircclient-dev  libtracker-sparql-0.14-dev libavahi-glib-dev librest-dev libavahi-client-dev tracker
   ```
2. Download the latest *media-explorer* 0.3.6.1 and extract it in one step:

   ```
   wget -O- https://github.com/downloads/media-explorer/media-explorer/media-explorer-0.3.6.1.tar.xz | tar -xJ
   ```
3. Fix the `configure` file because it does not recognize the `deprecated` soname in the latest clutter libraries, and because it depends on the old `tracker-sparql-0.12` library instead of the latest 0.14:

   ```
   cd media-explorer-0.3.6.1
   sed -i -e "s/\`\$PKG_CONFIG --variable soname_infix clutter-1.0\`/eglx/g" configure
   sed -i -e "s/sparql-0.12/sparql-0.14/g" configure
   ```
4. Configure, compile and install Media Explorer with:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install
   ```
5. Start *tracker* to index content with `tracker-control -S`, and start Media Explorer from the Launcher (or just `media-explorer`):

   [image]

Comment: Can I use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` to easily remove it later on?.

Comment: @UriHerrera, yes, I checked -- `checkinstall` works fine. You *may* need to use `sudo checkinstall`...

Answer (score 4):

You may or may not really want to do this.... There's always a chance when compiling software and using ppa's that you run a risk in creating an unstable, possibly unusable machine. I am sure that you know this already, but for other folks that may happen upon this post, you might not want to do this...

Here is what I did in order to install the latest version of media-explorer (media-explorer-0.3.4). I added the prague-demo ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zdra/prague-demo
```

This allowed for me to install all of the required dependencies that I was unable to resolve using my standard default repositories. I then updated my apt sources by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Here are the dependencies that are necessary to install in order to get the latest version of media-explorer to compile without errors. To install them run:

```
sudo apt-get install intltool libclutter-1.0-dev libsoupcutter-dev libmx-dev libgrilo-0.1-dev libgstreamermm-0.10-dev libclutter-gst-dev liblircclient-dev  libtracker-sparql-0.10-dev libavahi-glib-dev librest-dev libavahi-client-dev
```

Download the tar file from media-explorer's site:

```
wget https://github.com/downloads/media-explorer/media-explorer/media-explorer-0.3.4.tar.xz
```

Extract:

```
tar -xvf media-explorer-0.3.4.tar.xz
```

Then cd into the Directory:

```
cd media-explorer-0.3.4

./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install
```

You should then be able to launch `media-explorer`. There were a couple of warnings that appeared in my terminal, I am not familiar with this application, but do plan to play around with it a bit now!

[image: media-explorer running]
[image: media-explorer version]

Comment: Thank you very much!, have you figured out how to add anything to the libraries?

Comment: I was going to play with it more tonight, If I do, I will add some more info ;-)

Comment: @Uri One missing dependency, `sudo apt-get install tracker` you may have to accept some unsigned packages. Then you'll need to start the tracker mining by issuing the following command in a terminal: `tracker-control -S` after a short while you will see it begin indexing your locally available media. I had started media-explorer and opened a new tab in my terminal in order to start the mining. I haven't been able to do anything hitting any network shares yet.

Comment: Did you get this error?: `Attempting to use the media explorer tracker plugin but grilo tracker plugin not loaded. You may not see any content!`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting and continued to get even after I installed the tracker application and started it using `tracker-control -S`. My content began appearing and was usable, so I kind of just ignored it considering the state of development.